# How to repeat substrings

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how substrings can be accessed in python. In my code I'm trying to repeat all letters up to a single letter.

### For example:

x= hello

y=2

z=4

output= hehehehe

```
def f11():

    x= input('Enter a word: ')
    y= int(input('Enter a number: '))
    z= int(input('Enter the amount of times you want those letters repeated: '))

    if len(x) > 0 and x.isalpha():
       x[0:y:1]== letter
       letter * z== new_word
       print(new_word)
    else:
        print('Error no word input')
        f11()
f11()
```

The issue lies somewhere in

`x[0:y:1] == letter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slice notation to grab the part of the string you are interested in, then use the `*` operator to repeat the substring.

```
def repeatLetters(word, dist, rep):
    return word[:dist] * rep

>>> repeatLetters('hello', 3, 4)
'helhelhelhel'
```

Note that I used abbreviated slice notation

```
[:dist]
```

Which is equivalent to

```
[0 : dist : 1]
```

**Edit**
As a side note, you've got some Python syntax misunderstandings. Look at these lines for example.

```
x[0:y:1] == letter
letter * z== new_word
```

The `==` operator is an equality check, it says "does the left hand side equal the right hand side?". It is **not** an assignment operator, which would be `=`. That being said, even if you did use the assignment operator, you must assign right to left, for example

```
new_word = letter * z
```